# Array of Object Causes NullPointerException Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I do not know why but this line of code gives a `NullPointerException`. I searched creating array of an user obj. in Java, again but, I could not find any problem.

```
private State[] states;
.    
.
.
private void initializeStates( )
        {
            states = new State[ stateNames.length ]; // Throws NullPointerException

        for( int i = 0; i < stateNames.length; i++ )
        {
            states[i] = new State();
            states[i].setName( stateNames[i] );
            states[i].setColor( stateColors.getColor() );
        }
    } // End of initializeStates()
```

And here is the class:

```
public class State
{
    private String stateName;
    private String color;
    private boolean isStartState;
    private boolean isFinalState;

        State()
        {
            stateName = new String(); // Can this line cause nullPtrException?
            color = new String(); // Can this line cause nullPtrException?
            isStartState = false;
            isFinalState = false;
        }

        public void setName( String name ){ stateName = name; }
        public void setColor( String clr ) {   color = clr; }
        public void makeStart( ) {  isStartState = true; }
        public void makeFinal( ) {  isFinalState = true; }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and point to the line of the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this line throws the exception:

```
states = new State[ stateNames.length ]; // Throws NullPointerException
```

... then the problem is that `stateNames` is `null`. You're not making it as far as any of the rest of your code.

You haven't shown where `stateNames` is declared or initialized, but that's where you should look next.

As an aside, this:

```
stateName = new String();
```

... is inefficient for no reason. Just use an empty string literal:

```
stateName = "";
```

(Or better, take the appropriate initial values as constructor parameters.)